# How to construct an algorithm to move along a discrete grid at constant steps?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, tessellations

Assume we have a tessellation of cubes of length one of a 3D space.

We have a starting point $P$ and a direction $\vec V$ of length one.

Our goal is to move the point $P$ by direction $\vec V$ such that $P$ now lies exactly on the closest edge of the grid along that direction.
In other words, in 2D, if we have the point (0.5,0.5) and the direction (0.1,0.1) the result should be the point (1,1). If it was (0.5,0.5) and (1.0,0) the result should be (1,0.5) and so on...

This needs to be done in constant time (i.e $O(1)$).

What tools can I use to solve this?

Comment: $P$ lies within a unit square. Check whether each of the four edges of that square intersects the ray from $P$ with the given direction and move $P$ to the intersection.

Comment: With regard to the first sentence of the question: I do not know any tesselation of 3D space that uses only squares. Did you mean 2D?

Comment: I meant cubes actually, my bad